# I have exception in webapi 2

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am working on webapi 2 with ASP.NET and MySQL. When I want to insert data in local host with a column name ID which is auto increment compiler give me some error

```
Public void RegisterUser (UserRegisterations your)
{

        string Gender = ur.Gender;
        string Password = ur.Password;
        string Email = ur.Email;
        string DOB = ur.DOB;
        string City = ur.City;
        int TelePhone = ur.TelePhone;


        string query = $"INSERT INTO register( Email, TelePhone, Password, Gender, City, DOB)VALUES({Email},'{TelePhone}','{Password}','{Gender}','{City}','{DOB}')";
        //string query = "INSERT INTO register VALUES ('shahzad@gmail.com','a','2','a','a','a')";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Connection = Con;
        Con.Open();


        {
            if (Con != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successed");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("failure");
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: update your question and add  your exact error message

Comment: Your code is not proper you are not passing proper VALUES in a query "INSERT INTO register( Email, TelePhone, Password, Gender, City, DOB)VALUES({Email},'{TelePhone}','{Password}','{Gender}','{City}','{DOB}')"

You are not passing concating value that user passing. And what is "ur.Gender" as your method parameter name is your